# Problems while applying a function to a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, python-requests, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
lis = ['hi how are you', 'pretty good', 'lore lipsum dolor done', 'done lipsum dolor', 'lipsum dolor done', 'lipsum lore done', 'greetings']
```

And the following function, which is calling an API with requests library:

```
def my_req(text):

    payload = {'txt': text, 'param1': param1, 
    'param2': param2, 'param3': param3, 'param4': param4}

    r = requests.get('http://api.exmaple.com', params=payload, stream = True)
   try:
     json_data = json.dumps(r.json())
   except JSONDecodeError:
     np.nan

   data = yaml.load(json_data)
   foo(data['index'])
   return foos_list
```

I would like to apply the function to each element of `lis`. Thus, I tried this:

In:

```
lis = [my_req(item) for item in [lis]]
```

Comment: What type of argument does my_req take? Seems that it wants only a string argument. So make sure you are passing it a string.

Comment: The `except` block in function `my_req` is useless, because the function continues the execution in case of an exception as if nothing happened.

Comment: @J.Do... you need to analyze what you are passing and why. A list is different from a string. Forcing is not going to help. What does my_req return? I don't see a return statement.

Comment: lis = [my_req(item) for item in [lis]] is the same thing as saying lis = [my_req(lis)]. Those bracket things should not be tossed here and there. You need to understand lists starting with some simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for i in range(len(lis)):
    lis[i] = [my_req(item) for item in lis[i][0].split()]
```

Comment: I got: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: What are you storing in the inner list? isn't it string?

Comment: simply print n see : ```print(lis)```  or check the type

Comment: this code will call my_req in this order : my_req("hi"),my_req("how"), my_req("are"),my_req("you") and will store the result in a list. Is this what you want?

Comment: I want: my_req(''hi how are you''), my_req(''pretty good"), my_req('lore lipsum dolor done')....

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description and sample data, your input is a list of lists of strings, where each sublist has the length of 1, and you need this:

```
[my_req(item[0]) for item in lis]
```

This returns a list of lists of tuples. If you want to flatten it, use `itertools`:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_req(item[0]) for item in lis))
```

Comment: That's what your function `my_req` returns, and since you never asked about it, I have no idea what it is supposed to do and how to fix it.

Comment: Its weird because when I test it over just one sentence it returns a simple list of tuples...

Comment: The function body in your original post is a mess. For example, the function returns an undefined variable. You must fix it before seeking help on it.

Comment: I modified the original list into a list of strings... Do this can help in this situation?...

Comment: First, your change invalidates my answer. So good luck modifying it as well. Second, as I said, your function is a mess.

Comment: When I do: `my_req(['hi how are you'])` I get: `[('hi', 'hola', 'LN-'), ('how', 'how', 'K--'), ('are', 'arar', 'VS-S1PSATL-N1'), ('you', 'you', 'K--')]`, which is the expected output. I also did: `[my_req(item) for item in lis]`and it did not worked...